# How to determine what files a program is trying to open?

Tags: linux, file, debugging, executable

I have a program that I have compiled for a Linux server. It was written in FORTRAN, although I don't think that is particularly relevant to the question.

At some point, the program spits out `open: No such file or directory`

And then terminates.

The issue is I have no idea what file/directory the program is *attempting* to open.

It would be really great if there was some kind of program, a bit like `ldd` (but not quite) which could be run to show what files a binary executable is attempting to open.

Does such a thing exist? If not is there a way to obtain such information from the Linux kernel?

Comment: Is this a userland application or a kernel driver? You tagged kernel, but it sounds like you are asking about userland. And to state the obvious, you should provide meaningful error messages in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program called strace which can do this

`strace -f -e open <exe>`

See https://linux-audit.com/monitor-file-access-by-linux-processes/

Answer (score 5):

`man strace`

In your case `strace -e openat $YOURPOGRAM`.